# SQL replace HTML entity number/code with symbol

Tags: sql, ms-access, replace, html-entities

There are two source tables.
One contains product data (including short and long description of the product), the other contains HTML entity numbers/codes and its equivalent symbol.

T1:

```
 ID |          Short          |        Long
------------------------------------------------------
001 | Captain's Shield&trade; | Cool item&copy;
002 | Someones's Hammer&reg;  | Even cooler item&copy;
```

As you can see T1 can possibly contain HTML entity numbers/codes.

T2:

```
  HTML  | Symbol 
----------------------------------
&trade; |  ™
&reg;   |  ®
&copy;  |  ©
```

T2 contains "all" possible numbers/codes.

What I'd like to do is replace all occurences of such entities in columns "Short" and "Long".

The result should look like this:

```
 ID |          Short          |        Long
------------------------------------------------------
001 |    Captain's Shield™    | Cool item©
002 |    Someones's Hammer®   | Even cooler item©
```

Here is some example code I've tried and failed making it work properly:

```
UPDATE T1, T2
SET 
T1.Short = replace(T1.Short, T2.HTML, T2.Symbol), 
T1.Long = replace(T1.Long, T2.HTML, T2.Symbol)
WHERE UseRegExp(T1.Short, "^.*&((#[0-9]{1,5})|[a-zA-Z]{1,10});.*$")<>"" Or UseRegExp(T1.Long, "^.*&((#[0-9]{1,5})|[a-zA-Z]{1,10});.*$")<>"";
```

I'm aware that SQL's replace function only allows strings to be replaced, but I was not able to find any other function to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work, because the result is written actually at the end of the statement, not after each row is processed. This way each time a row is processed only the symbol joined to that row is replaced. In the next row the original row is taken as source again and the replace from the previous row is forgotten, so you actually never replace all symbols.

What you need to do is update the table multiple times, each time with a different row from T2. Or even better, you need to build yourself a statement with all entries from T2 if those aren't too many.

You can build such a statement like this:

```
select concat(
  repeat('replace(', count(*))
  , 't1.Short, '
  , group_concat(concat('\'', HTML, '\',\'', Symbol, '\')'))
  )
from t2;
```

Which returns

```
replace(replace(replace(t1.Short, '&trade;','™'),'&reg;','®'),'&copy;','©')
```

([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/258bdf/3/0))

Either use this to build a string for dynamic sql (read more about this [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)) or you simply build it once, copy it and execute your query. Your query would be

```
update T1 set 
Short = replace(replace(replace(T1.Short, '&trade;','™'),'&reg;','®'),'&copy;','©'),
Long = replace(replace(replace(T1.Long, '&trade;','™'),'&reg;','®'),'&copy;','©');
```

Comment: thank you! unfortunately ms access does not interpret the code as intended. It seems that concat() (I've found a replacement for that), repeat() (there is an equivalent for this: string() ) and group_concat() (I wasn't able to find a replacement for that function) functions cannot be found within access.